# Parâmetros prejudicam a física no método update do unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Bom, basicamente eu criei uma classe PlayerController e estava separando alguns métodos até criar um método PlayerMechanics(float jumpForce, etc...). Ao colocar este método dentro do Update() percebi que a física do pulo bugava e o personagem se teletransportava na coordenada y com o valor do jumpForce. o problema é que no método PlayerController eu usei o Time.deltaTime para fazer o cálculo da gravidade, mas quando eu tiro os parâmetros e chamo as variáveis diretamente todos comandos funcionam perfeitamente!

## vou colocar o trecho de código que funciona e embaixo o que buga!

Código sem bugs

```cs
void PlayerMechanics()
    {
        if (m_controller.isGrounded)
        {
            perceivedForceOnTheAxis = MovementInZAxis(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), speedMovement);
            perceivedForceOnTheAxis.y = Jump(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"), jumpForce);
        }
        m_controller.transform.Rotate(RotationInYAxis(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), speedRotation) * Time.deltaTime);
>        perceivedForceOnTheAxis.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
>        m_controller.Move(perceivedForceOnTheAxis * Time.deltaTime);
    }

void Update()
    {
>       PlayerMechanics();
    }
```

Código com bug

```cs
void PlayerMechanics(CharacterController m_controller, float perceivedForceOnTheAxis, float gravity, float speedMovement, float jumpForce, float speedRotation)
    {
        if (m_controller.isGrounded)
        {
            perceivedForceOnTheAxis = MovementInZAxis(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), speedMovement);
            perceivedForceOnTheAxis.y = Jump(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"), jumpForce);
        }
        m_controller.transform.Rotate(RotationInYAxis(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), speedRotation) * Time.deltaTime);
>        perceivedForceOnTheAxis.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
>        m_controller.Move(perceivedForceOnTheAxis * Time.deltaTime);
    }

void Update()
    {
>       PlayerMechanics(m_controller, perceivedForceOnTheAxis, gravity, speedMovement, jumpForce, speedRotation);
    }
```

O problema é exclusivamente quando eu invento de colocar os parâmetros!!!
Não sei se é uma prática ruim, mas achei interessante bugar só por isso.

Tinha pensado em fazer assim pra logo quando eu visse os parâmetros eu já saberia quais variáveis eu estava utilizando naquele método!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, existe um método chamado FixedUpdate(), ele é basicamente um Update que não roda a cada frame e sim em uma taxa de sincronização baseada na física da unity, perfeito para interações envolvendo movimento e física.

Answer (score 0):

Olha oque o amigo de cima falou é verdade, mas te dar uma dica de POO aqui, se você possui as variáveis que precisa, durante a chamada do método na classe, não há o porquê da utilização de parâmetros. Mas oque está acontecendo em seu código, não é que parâmetros bugam, mas quando você chama algo por parâmetro ele não muda a variável original, então no seu caso você está passando sempre os mesmos valores para o PlayerMechanics, você poderia resolver isso colocando "ref" na frente dos parâmetros. Para te dar um exemplo irei fazer uma simulação:

```
   m_controller = this.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
   perceivedForceOnTheAxis = 1;
   gravity = 9.8f;
   speedMovement = 3;
   jumpForce = 3;
   speedRotation = 2;
    void PlayerMechanics()
        {
            if (m_controller.isGrounded)
            {
                perceivedForceOnTheAxis = MovementInZAxis(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), speedMovement);
                perceivedForceOnTheAxis.y = Jump(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"), jumpForce);
            }
            m_controller.transform.Rotate(RotationInYAxis(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), speedRotation) * Time.deltaTime);
    >        perceivedForceOnTheAxis.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    >        m_controller.Move(perceivedForceOnTheAxis * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    void Update()
        {
    >       PlayerMechanics();
        }
```

No final, as variáveis mudariam seu valor após a chamada o método PlayerMechanics, pois você mexeu diretamente nelas.

```
m_controller = this.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
       perceivedForceOnTheAxis = 1;
       gravity = 9.8f;
       speedMovement = 3;
       jumpForce = 3;
       speedRotation = 2;

void PlayerMechanics(CharacterController m_controller, float perceivedForceOnTheAxis, float gravity, float speedMovement, float jumpForce, float speedRotation)
    {
        if (m_controller.isGrounded)
        {
            perceivedForceOnTheAxis = MovementInZAxis(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), speedMovement);
            perceivedForceOnTheAxis.y = Jump(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"), jumpForce);
        }
        m_controller.transform.Rotate(RotationInYAxis(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), speedRotation) * Time.deltaTime);
>        perceivedForceOnTheAxis.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
>        m_controller.Move(perceivedForceOnTheAxis * Time.deltaTime);
    }

void Update()
    {
>       PlayerMechanics(m_controller, perceivedForceOnTheAxis, gravity, speedMovement, jumpForce, speedRotation);
    }
```

No final da chamada do método PlayerMechanics, elas continuariam com o mesmo valor, pois quando você passa por parâmetro, você cria uma nova instância na memória. Então você estaria chamando no Update sempre o mesmo método com os mesmos valores, acredito que deva estar em loop indo para mesma direção e iniciando do zero.